# Windows 10 and OpenVPN: suddenly no internet

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN to connect to a remote server. It worked all fine until a couple of days ago. Suddenly there is no internet, nor I can connect to anything else on there (like mysql server etc.)

I haven't changed any settings. The VPN provider said they haven't changed anything either. It's frustrating.

When I'm connected the VPN adapter status shows me that there are no "packets received". Is this a firewall thing, and why is it suddenly blocking everything?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with the OpenVPN Connect app as well, have you tried to use the openvpn-gui instead? It does not feature such a nice interface, but it works quite well for my needs, it searches the standard directories for profiles, then asks for a username and a password, connects with the server while also showing useful extracts of the connection log, and then minimizes into the sys tray until you click on the little icon.